# What time corresponds to : time()-24*60*60 ? (PHP)

Tags: php, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

What time corresponds to

```
time()-24*60*60
```

7 days? is that right?

Comment: Honestly, it fails me to see how one can even assume that this could amount to 7 days - it is not even a multiple of 7!

Comment: @polygenelubricants What you said is out of order imho.

Comment: Well, at least it made me laugh. Congratulations Tristan, you're the first person to genuinely amuse me today.

Comment: no problem, i've got my answer, so if I make your day happy, i'm glad ;)
Thanks

Comment: @Sbm007, @Tristan: I'm sorry if my original comment was out of order, but the utter lack of common sense is what got me. It's okay to make mistakes (and learn from them), but do make _educated guesses_, not _arbitrary baseless assumptions_.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

time `24 hours` ago.

`time()` returns the current Unix `timestamp` which is number of `seconds` since the Unix Epoch. Also there are `24` hours in a day and `60` min in an hour and `60` sec in a min.

Comment: I wanted to upvote but I don't want to ruin it for you.

Answer (score 9):

**time()** works with seconds, so:

```
60 * 60 = 3600 seconds (1 hour)
24 * 1 hour = 1 day
24 * 60 * 60 = 1 day
```

Answer (score 6):

One day ago actually. You're missing a 7 * if you need 7 days...

Answer (score 1):

year=365.3days day=24hours, hour=60minutes, minute=60seconds, and there's all those second=1000milliseconds etc.

if you have 5 days and you need hours then you do 5days*24hours=5*24=120hours

if you have 123hours and need days you do, 123h/1day=123/24=5.125days

so you can go 3years=3*365days=1095day=1095*24hours=26280=etc or for faster calculation you can just do 3years=3years*365days*24hours*60minutes*60seconds*1000milliseconds=big number of milliseconds

and you can do same otherway around 5000milliseconds=5000ms/1000ms/60s/60min/24hours/365days=very small number of years